# Find visual parent before loaded event was called

Tags: c#, wpf, parent-child, visualtreehelper

Is it possible in WPF to find a visual parent of an object (`UIElement`) before the loaded event was triggered? If i search for a specific parent in the loaded event, every thing works fine. If i search for a specific parent in the constructor after `LoadComponent`, it does not work. Or do i have to use the logical tree?

I use the `VisualTreeHelper` for searching.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF only inserts the elements into the tree (logical or visual) after the constructor was called. So you cannot find the parent elements in the constructor.

It wouldn't make sense to insert something that does not exist yet into the tree.

Comment: Ok, so the best thing is, using the loaded event... Thank you

Comment: Exactly. I know, sometimes it would be easier to use the constructor for these things, but it is sadly not possible